# Debouncing/Stabilizing power supply rocker switch?

Tags: power-supply, pic, debounce

I'm having trouble with the power signal out of my Rocker Switch (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8837 for reference).

My PIC18F4550 + 16x2 character LCD screen project was running fine until I added a Rocker switch to break the +5V line. Now, 50% of the times the LCD screen backlight will turn ON, but no message will display. This does not happen when I leave the Rocker switch in it's bridging position and plug/unplug the DC barrel jack directly (which has much fewer bouncing problems due to it's mechanism).

I do have a Power ON timer configured in my PIC program, which should give me around 60ms before going into the program, but apparently it isn't enough. It's also worth noting that whenever I press the Rocker switch VERY SLOWLY, I don't get the problem (thus, pointing to bouncing problem again).

Concept:
[image: +5V Line with switch]

Do you guys think it's a debouncing problem? How do you recommend me tackling this? Hopefully, if it's indeed a bouncing problem, we can fix it with caps and resistors only.

PS: The TO_PIC line on the picture not only goes to the PIC voltage pins, but it also goes to a LD33V Chip

Bit more complete circuit:
[image: With the voltage regulator]

Answer (score 1):

As Debounce you can add a cap. But a little better is an RC Lowpass, because a cap alone causes big currents when turning on which could harm your switch (mostly only if the cap is a little bigger).

If you need a fast changing Signal then you can put a schmitt trigger after the lowpass and an unloading resistor parallel to the capacitor. This is a luxus version, but more proper than just a cap.

If it's a hobby project try it with a cap but if the switch needs to last long time try the other one with the low pass.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think about filters lol, it might be that I'm used to thinking about them in a more "signals" environment. I'll try it and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hook up a scope to your circuit so you can determine the magnitude and duration of the bounce.  You then have a couple of options. The simplest might be to use a switch with better characteristics. Otherwise (if timing is not ns critical and you can edit the PIC code) get your PIC to sample the pin at a slower rate and average the readings. Eg if the sample rate is 5ms and the average of the last 5 samples is low, assume low.

Comment: Well that would be a software debounce, but I'm not entirely sure you can do that with the Vdd pin right? And that's the point of that Switch, it's not I/O

Comment: Ahh you are spot on I didn't process the second schematic properly. In that case a cap would absorb the bounce. Do you have a scope to measure it? if so try a few cap values and see which ones are most effective.